# Is retreated vs gets retreated

Tags: grammar

> I will come and collect it once the lockdown **is retreated**.

Should I replace the bold text with "has retreated" or " gets retreated"? Also, how do I know when to use "get" in such sentences?

Comment: You don't want ***any*** auxiliary verb in your context. Just *...once the lockdown **retreats***. But that's not a very good main verb anyway. As a rule, simpler words are usually better:  *...once the lockdown **ends*** (or ***has ended*** if you really want to include an auxiliary verb).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think "retreated" is the right word there. You might consider "is lifted" or "is rescinded" or "is canceled".

Comment: Will the sentence be still meaningful after changing the word?

Comment: It would be much more meaningful.

Comment: Should I use 'is lifted' or 'gets lifted'?

Comment: @santhosha Assuming you mean after the requirement of lockdown has been removed, then you could use either "is lifted" or "gets lifted". Even better, consider "once the lockdown has been lifted".